# Computing the Fourier transform with respect to the spatial variable in the Delta distribution.

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

[image]

This image is in the book "Basic partial differential equations" by Treves.

Hi. I have a doubt with respect to the Fourier transform of an differential equations. In the image, The Fourier transform of $\partial_t E$ is $\partial_t \bar{E}$. The verification of this is the following (my attempt):

If $\mathcal{F}_{\xi}$ indicates the Fourier transform with respect to the spatial variable, then:
\begin{align}
([\mathcal{F}_{\xi}(\partial_t (E(\xi,t))](x,t),\varphi(x,t))&=(\partial_t E(x,t),[\mathcal{F}_{\xi}\varphi(\xi,t)](x,t))\\
&=(E(x,t),\partial_t [\mathcal{F}_{\xi}\varphi(\xi,t)](x,t))\\
&=(E(x,t), [\mathcal{F}_{\xi}( \partial_t\varphi(\xi,t))](x,t)\\
&=([\mathcal{F}_{\xi}E(\xi,t)](x,t)\partial_t \varphi(x,t))\\
&=(\partial_t [\mathcal{F}_{\xi}E(\xi,t)](x,t),\varphi(x,t))
\end{align}
So, $$([\mathcal{F}_{\xi}(\partial_t (E(\xi,t))](x,t),\varphi(x,t))=(\partial_t [\mathcal{F}_{\xi}E(\xi,t)](x,t),\varphi(x,t))$$ for all $\varphi(x,t)$. This implies that $$[\mathcal{F}_{\xi}(\partial_t (E(\xi,t))](x,t)=\mathcal{F}_{\xi}E(\xi,t)](x,t)$$  (i.e. $\widehat{\partial_t E}=\partial_t \widehat{E})$

Question 1. Is the above correct? (Maybe I'm missing a factor $(-i)$ but I mean the idea.

Question 2. Why Fourier of $\delta$ is $\delta(t)$? I don't understanding this. I tried the following:

\begin{align}
(\mathcal{F}_{\xi}\delta,\phi)&=(\delta,[\mathcal{F}_{\xi}(\phi(\xi,t)](x,t))\\
&=(\mathcal{F}_{\xi}(\phi(\xi,t))\Bigg|_{(x,t)=(0,0)}?\\
&=\left(\int \mathrm{e}^{-ix\cdot \xi}\phi(\xi,t)d\xi\right)\Bigg|_{(x,t)=(0,0)\text{ or } (x,t)=(0,t)}?
\end{align}

Comment: I see. Then, $([\mathcal{F}_{\xi}(\delta(\xi)\delta(t))](x,t),\varphi(x,t))=([\mathcal{F}_{\xi}(\delta(\xi))](x,t) \cdot\delta(t),\varphi(x,t))=(1\cdot \delta(t),\varphi(x,t))$ with 1 distribution.

Comment: I have one last question. So $\delta$ means $\delta(x)\delta(t)$ where $(\delta(x),\varphi(y,t))=\varphi(y=x,t)\text{ or } \varphi(y=0,t)$? (Analogous with $\delta(t)$)

Comment: In what reference could I find that $\delta=\delta(x)\delta(t)$?